# Access Anki history from SQLite3 file

Tags: database, sqlite, anki

I want to perform some data analysis of my own on my Anki history.

I found out that my history should be contained in `~/.local/share/Anki2/User 1/collection.anki2`.
The file info says that this file is of type `SQLite3 database (application/vnd.sqlite3)`.

How can I open this file? (Could be with Python or with some dedicated software)

*PS: I am clueless about database-related stuff*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open `collection.anki2` with `sqlite3`(CLI) or `sqlitebrowser`(GUI)

For example, the database from the apkg archive

```
user@debian:~/Documents/anki$ sqlite3 collection.anki2
SQLite version 3.27.2 2019-02-25 16:06:06
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> .tables
cards   col     graves  notes   revlog
sqlite> .exit
```